# Radioactive decay function to find when mass reches 1 gram

Tags: functions

This is a quite specific question that I need help with so I'm going to ask it in a new post.

One thousand grams of a particular radioactive substance decays according to the mass function

$$m(t) = 1000e^{\frac{-t}{850}}$$

where t measures time in years.

When does the mass of the substance reach 1 gram?

Edit: So I was informed by 5xum to show a bit of my thought process on this question as well. Well, to be honest when I got this question I was completely lost on how to approach it. From a hint by qbert: $$1=1000e^{-\frac t{850}}$$
for $t$. Am I correct in presuming I am to divide both sides by 1000 and simplify, giving me $$e^{\frac{-t}{850}} = \frac1{1000}$$

And from here to get the natural log of both sides and applying a log rule and simplifying $\frac{-t}{850}ln(e)$ to just give us $\frac{-t}{850}$.

And for the other side ($ln(\frac{1}{1000})$) we are to use the rules of logarithms to make it $-ln(1000)$ and then $-ln(10^3)$ to finally apply the rules of logarithms again to make it $-3ln(10)$. Making the equation to now be $$-\frac{t}{850} = -3ln(10)$$

Where do I go from here to solve the equation?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry! I am new to stack exchange as you can probably guess and/or see from my profile. I actually asked this here because I was honestly completely lost on how to approach this question as I'm still extremely new to functions. Sorry ^-^, I'll try to keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. It is now a very well phrased question, well done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already proved that the equation you need to solve is equivalent to

$$-\frac{t}{850}=-3\ln(10)$$

Now, multiply the equation by $-850$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This is asking you to solve
$$
1=1000e^{-\frac t{850}}
$$
for $t$. The function $m$ takes in values of time, and spits out the mass of the radioactive substance at that time.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks so much. Sorry, but what is "exp"? (Other than experience points in games). Or is it just 3 variables?

Comment: it is the exponential function. Sorry, I will use notation you are used to